# Updated to Zpanel 10.1.0 500 error on login

Tags: php, linux

Running centos 6.4

updated zpanel to 10.1.0 now recieve a 500 error when trying to login, logs show the following errors:

[Tue Oct 08 02:08:33 2013] [error] [client 94.4.6.3] PHP Notice: Undefined index: ac_catorder_vc in /etc/zpanel/panel/dryden/ctrl/users.class.php on line 67

[Tue Oct 08 02:08:33 2013] [error] [client 94.4.6.3] PHP Notice: Undefined index: ip in /etc/zpanel/panel/dryden/runtime/sessionsecurity.class.php on line 135

[Tue Oct 08 02:08:33 2013] [error] [client 94.4.6.3] PHP Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /etc/zpanel/panel/dryden/runtime/sessionsecurity.class.php on line 126

[Tue Oct 08 02:08:47 2013] [error] [client 94.4.6.3] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ac_passsalt_vc' in 'field list'' in /etc/zpanel/panel/inc/init.inc.php:108\nStack trace:\n#0 /etc/zpanel/panel/inc/init.inc.php(108): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 /etc/zpanel/panel/index.php(18): require_once('/etc/zpanel/pan...')\n#2 {main}\n thrown in /etc/zpanel/panel/inc/init.inc.php on line 108, referer: http://xx.xxx.xxx/?loggedout

any guidance much appreciated.
It appears that the everything but the sql update scripts executed.

Is their a script that I can execute standalone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get it work. What I am posting here is not official but it worked for me. it seems something was missed from version 10.0.1 to 10.1.0. Lets see if what I did can help you.

My environment is Ubuntu 12 and I came from version 10.0.1 to 10.1.0. I got the same error you got, though.

As the updater did not work for me completely, I downloaded the source code to figure out the differences among the versions. The tar ball can be gotten here https://github.com/zpanel/zpanelx/archive/10.1.0.tar.gz.

After you extract it, you will see a folder called etc/build/config_packs/ubuntu_12_04/zpanelx-update and the directory for versions 10-0-1, 10-0-2 and 10-1-0. You will need to start from your original version. By this I mean, if you are updating from version 10.0.1 to 10.1.0, you will need to use scripts from 10.0.2 and 10.0.1.

Lets follow this example. Open the file panel_update.sql from 10-0-2/sql folder. You will see an content similar to:

```
/* Update SQL for CentOS 6 ZPanel 10.0.1 to 10.0.2 */
USE `zpanel_core`;

/* Change field length for passwords */
    ALTER TABLE `zpanel_core`.`x_accounts`
    CHANGE COLUMN `ac_pass_vc` `ac_pass_vc` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL;

/* New setting for turning off CSRF on login form */
INSERT IGNORE INTO `x_settings`(`so_id_pk`,`so_name_vc`,`so_cleanname_vc`,`so_value_tx`,`so_defvalues_tx`,`so_desc_tx`,`so_module_vc`,`so_usereditable_en`) VALUES (117,'login_csfr','Remote Login Forms','false','false|true','Disables CSFR protection on the login form to enable remote login forms.','ZPanel Config','true');

/* Remove and update standard FAQs */
DELETE FROM `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` WHERE `fq_id_pk` > 0 AND `fq_id_pk` < 18;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (1,1,'How can I update my personal contact details?','From the control panel homepage please click on the &quot;My Account&quot; icon to enable you to update your personal details.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (2,1,'How do I change my password?','Your ZPanel and MySQL password can be easily changed using the &quot;Change Password&quot; icon on the control panel.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (3,1,'I don&#39;t think one of the services(Apache, MySQL, FTP, etc) are running. Is there any easy way to check?','ZPanel comes with a service monitoring system that checks to make sure all the services are up and running, Simply go to your Control Panel Home and select the module called &quot;Service Status&quot;. From there you will be able to see if any of the services are down or up.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (4,1,'How can I set my domain to work with my ZPanel Account?','To setup up a domain with ZPanel first thing you need to do is go &quot;Domains&quot; and add your to the list. Next you need to set the Name Server on your Domain Registrar to match that of your host. This information can be obtained by contacting your host.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (7,1,'How can I create a MySQL Database?','To create a MySQL database simply go to the section of the panel called &quot;Database Management&quot; and select the module called &quot;MySQL Databases&quot; from here you will easily be able to add and manage databases on your account.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (8,1,'What is phpMyAdmin?','phpMyAdmin is an open source tool intended to handle the administration of MySQL databases. It can perform various tasks such as creating, modifying or deleting databases, tables, fields or rows or executing SQL statements',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (9,1,'How do I create FTP Accounts?','You can create FTP accounts by going to &quot;FTP Accounts&quot; from their you can add accounts and manage quotas and directories. ',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (10,1,'How to Password Protect Directories?','Go to Advanced and select the module &quot;Password Protect Directories&quot; From here you can generate .htaccess files to lock down directories on your site to only people with a login and password.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (11,1,'How do I create an E-Mail Account?','Go to the Mail section of ZPanel and select the module called &quot;Mailboxes&quot;, from here you can create E-Mail account for each domain setup on your account. You can also reset passwords to previously created accounts.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (12,1,'How do I create a Mail Alias?','Go to the Mail section of ZPanel and select the module called &quot;Aliases&quot;, from here you can create Alias E-Mail accounts for each previously created E-Mail account. All mail sent to the alias will be delivered to the master e-mail account.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (13,1,'How can I create a Mailing List?','Mailing lists can be setup by going to the Mail section of ZPanel and select the module called &quot;Distribution Lists&quot;, from here you can create Mailing lists by creating an E-mail Account. ',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (14,1,'How do I use Mail Forwards?','Go to the Mail section of ZPanel and select the module called &quot;Forwards&quot;, from here you can create E-Mail address on your domains that will forward to other E-Mail addresses that are on different servers like &quot;G-Mail, Yahoo, and MSN&quot;. ',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (15,1,'What are Subdomains?','A subdomain combines a unique identifier with a domain name to become essentially a &quot;domain within a domain.&quot; The unique identifier simply replaces the www in the web address. Yahoo!, for example, uses subdomains such as mail.yahoo.com and music.yahoo.com to reference its mail and music services, under the umbrella of www.yahoo.com. They can be created by using the Subdomain module in the Domains section. You can assign directories for each sub domain from the module.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (16,1,'How can I view how much Data I have used?','You can view how much data you have used by accessing the &quot;Usage Viewer&quot; under the Account Information section of ZPanel. It displays account information in different formats. It displays Data Usage, Domain Usage, Bandwidth Usage, MySQL Usage, and much more.',1,NULL,NULL);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zpanel_core`.`x_faqs` (`fq_id_pk`,`fq_acc_fk`,`fq_question_tx`,`fq_answer_tx`,`fq_global_in`,`fq_created_ts`,`fq_deleted_ts`) VALUES (17,1,'How can I access Webmail?','Go to the Mail section of ZPanel and select the module called &quot;Webmail&quot;, from here you can login to your E-Mail account and view and create messages. ',1,NULL,NULL);

/* Force DNS and Apache rewrite configs */
UPDATE `zpanel_core`.`x_settings` SET `so_value_tx`=',0' WHERE `so_name_vc`='dns_hasupdates';
UPDATE `zpanel_core`.`x_settings` SET `so_value_tx`='true' WHERE `so_name_vc`='apache_changed';


/* Update the ZPanel database version number */
UPDATE  `zpanel_core`.`x_settings` SET  `so_value_tx` =  '10.0.2' WHERE  `so_name_vc` = 'dbversion';
```

Apply it to your panel_core database. After apply it, go to folder 10-1-0 and grab the file panel_update.sql from folder 10-1-0/sql. The content is similar to:

```
/* Update SQL for Ubuntu 12.04 ZPanel 10.0.2 to 10.0.3 */
USE `zpanel_core`;

UPDATE `zpanel_core`.`x_settings` SET `so_value_tx`='/var/zpanel/logs/zpanel.log' WHERE `so_name_vc`='logfile';
ALTER TABLE  `x_accounts` ADD  `ac_catorder_vc` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL AFTER  `ac_passsalt_vc`;

/* split crontab into seperate storage */
DELETE FROM `x_settings` WHERE `so_name_vc` = 'cron_reload';
INSERT INTO `x_settings`(`so_name_vc`,`so_cleanname_vc`,`so_value_tx`,`so_defvalues_tx`,`so_desc_tx`,`so_module_vc`,`so_usereditable_en`) VALUES ('cron_reload_command','Cron Reload Command','crontab',NULL,'Crontab binary in Linux Only','Cron Config','true');
INSERT INTO `x_settings`(`so_name_vc`,`so_cleanname_vc`,`so_value_tx`,`so_defvalues_tx`,`so_desc_tx`,`so_module_vc`,`so_usereditable_en`) VALUES ('cron_reload_path','Cron Reload Path','/var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data',NULL,'Cron reload path in Linux Only','Cron Config','true');
INSERT INTO `x_settings`(`so_name_vc`,`so_cleanname_vc`,`so_value_tx`,`so_defvalues_tx`,`so_desc_tx`,`so_module_vc`,`so_usereditable_en`) VALUES ('cron_reload_flag','Cron Reload Flags','-u',NULL,'Cron reload command flags in Linux Only','Cron Config','true');
INSERT INTO `x_settings`(`so_name_vc`,`so_cleanname_vc`,`so_value_tx`,`so_defvalues_tx`,`so_desc_tx`,`so_module_vc`,`so_usereditable_en`) VALUES ('cron_reload_user','Cron Reload User','www-data',NULL,'Cron reload apache user in Linux','Cron Config','true');

/* Reset theme for all users due to new theme which breaks older themes. */
UPDATE `x_accounts` SET `ac_usertheme_vc` = 'zpanelx';

/* Drop the redunent x_mysql table */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `zpanel_core`.`x_mysql`;

/* Adds additonal shared domains, 'autono.de' and 'zphub.com' of which users can register at bindhub.com */
UPDATE `x_settings` SET `so_value_tx` = IFNULL(CONCAT(`so_value_tx`, ',autono,zphub'), ",autono,zphub") WHERE `so_name_vc` = 'shared_domains';

/* Update the ZPanel database version number */
UPDATE  `zpanel_core`.`x_settings` SET  `so_value_tx` =  '10.1.0' WHERE  `so_name_vc` = 'dbversion';
```

Beside, you can update the zadmin password running the following command:

```
/etc/zpanel/panel/bin/setzadmin <newpass>
```

Those 3 "patches" should be enough to get you logged in.

Unfortunately, I don't know what else is missing. I am able to operate the tool and in a high level analysis, everything sounds good. I will keep using it and update here if I find anything else.